# Passing data from rails controller to react component

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, node.js, ruby, reactjs

I'm trying to integrate rails with react via webpacker, but i dont know how to pass in example `@post = Post.all` from controller to react component props. I have to do this by api or there is other way??

Comment: Yep, according to https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/ruby-ruby-on-rails/building-a-crud-interface-with-react-and-ruby-on-rails you need to create an api that you will hit from your React front-end.

Comment: You need to do it by API so you'll have to have two servers running.

Comment: While you do need to do it through an API, you definitely can accomplish this using a single server.  If you desire a separation of concerns, that's not a bad idea, but it's not necessary either.

Comment: If react is just V of MVC structure so there shouldn't be a way to pass data to component like passing to erb?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is another way:

some_views.html.erb

```
<%= javascript_tag do %>
  var appointments = <%= raw(@appointments.to_json) %>
<% end %>
```

some_react_components.js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const data = window.appointments
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Appointments appointments={data} />,
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div')),
  )
})
```

Answer (score 3):

I find solution by my self. https://hackernoon.com/how-to-get-your-rails-data-into-your-react-component-with-webpacker-647dc63706c9

By adding content tag to view where I want to render react component and pass props as attributes.

```
<%= content_tag :div,
  id: "appointments_data",
  data: @appointments.to_json do %>
<% end %>
```

then parse data and add it do props

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const node = document.getElementById('appointments_data')
  const data = JSON.parse(node.getAttribute('data'))
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Appointments appointments={data} />,
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div')),
  )
})
```